# Get data from SAP to Salesforce using WSDL

Tags: apex, rest-api, soap-api, webservices, wsdl2apex

I have attached the WSDL2Apex class for getting data Sap to Salesforce. I am bit confused about this Apex code is correct or not for this WSDL file which is to connect the WSDL to get data from SAP.//Generated by wsdl2apex

```
public class sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS {
    public class zsd_cust_det_webservice {
        public String endpoint_x = 'http://serverapp5.css.local:80/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zsd_cust_det_webservice/100/zsd_cust_det_webservice/zsd_cust_det_webservice';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style', 'sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS', 'urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions', 'sapComDocumentSapRfcFunctions'};
        public sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZsdTCustDet ZsdCustWebservDemo(String IvAcctNo) {
            sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZsdCustWebservDemo_element request_x = new sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZsdCustWebservDemo_element();
            sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZsdCustWebservDemoResponse_element response_x;
            request_x.IvAcctNo = IvAcctNo;
            Map<String, sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZsdCustWebservDemoResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZsdCustWebservDemoResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              '',
              'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',
              'ZsdCustWebservDemo',
              'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',
              'ZsdCustWebservDemoResponse',
              'sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZsdCustWebservDemoResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.EtAccDet;
        }
    }
    public class ZsdCustWebservDemo_element {
        public String IvAcctNo;
        private String[] IvAcctNo_type_info = new String[]{'IvAcctNo','urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions','char10','1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style','false','true'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'IvAcctNo'};
    }
    public class ZsdSCustDet {
        public String AcctNo;
        public String SalesOrdNo;
        public String PoNo;
        public String PoDate;
        public String NetVal;
        public String Currency_x;
        private String[] AcctNo_type_info = new String[]{'AcctNo','urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions','char10','1','1','false'};
        private String[] SalesOrdNo_type_info = new String[]{'SalesOrdNo','urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions','char10','1','1','false'};
        private String[] PoNo_type_info = new String[]{'PoNo','urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions','char20','1','1','false'};
        private String[] PoDate_type_info = new String[]{'PoDate','urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions','date','1','1','false'};
        private String[] NetVal_type_info = new String[]{'NetVal','urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions','curr15.2','1','1','false'};
        private String[] Currency_x_type_info = new String[]{'Currency','urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions','cuky5','1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style','false','true'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'AcctNo','SalesOrdNo','PoNo','PoDate','NetVal','Currency_x'};
    }
    public class ZsdTCustDet {
        public sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZsdSCustDet[] item;
        private String[] item_type_info = new String[]{'item','urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style','ZsdSCustDet','0','-1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style','false','true'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'item'};
    }
    public class ZsdCustWebservDemoResponse_element {
        public sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZsdTCustDet EtAccDet;
        private String[] EtAccDet_type_info = new String[]{'EtAccDet','urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style','ZsdTCustDet','1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style','false','true'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'EtAccDet'};
    }
}

Apex code:
public class test
{

    public test(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }


    public test(set<SAP__c> i)
{

list<SAP__c>lic=[select Name from SAP__c where id in: i];
for( SAP__c s:lic)
{

sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.zsd_cust_det_webservice create=new sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.zsd_cust_det_webservice();
 create.ZsdCustWebservDemo(s.Name);

}
}
}
```

Comment: What specifically are you confused about ?

Answer (score 5):

There is an excellent topic '**Understanding the Generated Code**' in the Apex Developers guide [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_gen_code.htm), which describes what your getting from the Apex2WSDL tool and an example of how to use it. Of course each Web Service is different, so I cannot comment on specifically. So here are some general observations.

- **Authentication?** I can see that its a basic account enquiry service. It does not appear to have any authentication needs (typically these are expressed in the WSDL via soap:header's), i assume thats ok for your demo purposes.
- **Bulkification?** If you are in control of the web service you may want to ask the author to accept a list of customer names, which will avoid you looping over them. Note that Apex has a limit of 10 maximum call outs of this kind per request. Limiting the number of records from your SAP__c table that can be processed.

Finally you should also review the support for [Mocking Web Service callouts](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm) when it comes time to write some Apex tests to cover this code you will need it.